# Error saving system information. Access is denied. Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, access-denied

I'm getting this painful error everytime I try to save my project for the last couple of days.
I've tried running android studio as administrator but I still get the same error.
I've tried to go to that path but the folder .AndroidStudio doesn't appears under User\Lucian\, and I can access the folder through the Address bar, but the folder seems to be empty.
I'd appreciate any directions on where I should be looking.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue since I installed Android Studio several weeks ago.

Today I found out that the 'Android1.3' folder (and some sub-folders) were invisible. Since I turned on the visibility of this folder, I am no longer getting this error. :)

Hope this will help you too.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the path mentioned inside the error message. If you see any hidden folders listed in there change its properties and set its visibility to normal.

For example, C:\Users\Username\.AndroidStudio2.1 was hidden in my system. Removing the hidden properties worked for me.